# How can i generate scripts in Pipfile through setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, pipenv

I would like to also generate this section in Pipfile

```
[scripts]
build = "my build command"
```

through `setuptools.setup()` unfortunately i couldn't find any documentation on which attribute handles these custom scripts.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. The `setup` function is normally called when distributing your package. The `[scripts]` section is normally manually filled-up to specify custom or shortcut CLI commands on your pipenv shell (ex. `pipenv run build` runs some build script). The Pipfile is used to install dependencies as *you* develop the package. The setuptools is for distributing your package, and has its own `install_requires` section which is what gets installed on *other* people's env when they install your package. Can you clarify the workflow you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Furthermore, the Pipfile is not normally distributed with the package, so it's not available when users install your package with setuptools.

Comment: i was confused as i was thinking that setup.py is generating the Pipfile. Seems like they coexist and some things are showing up in both (i.e. install_requires and [requires] which are basically the same). Seems like there is not yet a a standard in the python world for handling dependencies in a single file (like package.json in npm)